# Flows are not shown completely in the Solution section of Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerapp, power-automate, microsoft-flow

***If this is not the best forum for this question, please advise, thanks***

I have created some flows in my solution in Power automate as shown below:

**Fig 1.**

[image]

When I want to create a parent flow, I can see the old child flows that I removed but I cannot see the new child flow that I have created recently. I cannot find these flows (e.g. IdentifyChanges4Email_v1) that are shown in the dropdown list anywhere in my solution and I cannot find the recent child (i.e.Child_SpotChanes4Parroval_Email) that I created in the solution. I can't understand why this has happened and how to fix this. In simple words, why the flows that I can see in the dropdwonlist of **Fig 4** is different from what I see in **Fig 1**.

I can't remember how I removed those flows that are shown in the drop-down list of "Run as a child", as there are two options:

**Fig 2.**

[image]

The Url of the Child_SpotChanes4Parroval_Email
flow.microsoft.com/manage/environments/Default-8d73b928-6d5e-4c72-8533-a45ec5d6cc2b/solutions/6e1170ab-0edc-part2-000d3a6aa1e4/flows/d68efa2a-04da-41cc-b349-536b7a35b476

**Fig 3.**
[image]

The Url of Parent Flow:
flow.microsoft.com/manage/environments/Default-Part1-a45ec5d6cc2b/solutions/6e1170ab-part2-000d3a6aa1e4/flows/....

**Fig 4.**
[image]

As shown by the URL both parent and child are in the same solution.

and the connection string of the child (i.e. Child_SpotChanes4Parroval_Email)

**Fig 5.**

[image]

and my licenses are:

**Fig 6.**

[image]

The whole thing was working a few days ago very well but it messed up yesterday and I guess this might be because of my licensing issue as I have started seeing the trial message as shown below:

**Fig 7.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another [Power Automate](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Get-Help-with-Power-Automate/ct-p/FL_GeneralDiscussions) forum where you might also get help from.

Please note that this is a feature under construction. It is better that you contact Microsoft directly (via Service Request or other methods) if you cannot sort the issues out.

---

The expiration prompt might be the scenario mentioned in this blog: [Helpful tips for using Child Flows](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/helpful-tips-for-using-child-flows/), according to which, proceed with the trial if prompted will resolve this issue.

Per my test:

1. If you removed the child flows via `Remove > Remove from this solution`, the child flow remains in the drop down list in the *Run a Child Flow* action, and can be added back to the solution via `Add existing > Flow > From solutions`. *Delete from this environment* will remove this child flow permanently.
2. Flows created directly in the solution (including parent flows) will instantly show up in the drop-down list, even if they are not well configured.
3. Flows added to the solution do not necessarily show up in the drop-down list (in my test none of them showed up). You can see the reference here for the limitations while using the solution: [Solutions overview - Known limitations.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/common-data-service/solutions-overview#known-limitations)

I suggest you start another trial and then test again. Create a new child flow in the solution and see if you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Thanks @chelsea_MSFT for the links and the suggested forum, much appreciated.